# Whether $L=\{(a^m,a^n)\}^*$ is regular or not?

Tags: abstract-algebra, formal-languages, automata, semigroups

I am condidering the automatic structure for Baumslag-Solitar semigroups. And I have a question. For any $m,n \in Z$, whether the set $L=\{(a^m,a^n)\}^*$ is regular or not. Here a set is regular means it can be recognized by a finite automaton.

Since the operations:union, intersection, complement, concatenation and Kleene star for the regular sets are closed (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language)), I have tried to represent $L$ to be the result of some sets under the operations mentioned above. If it is successfully represented, $L$ will be regular. But I failed. So I want to ask for some clues for this question.

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Do you mean $L=\{a^m,a^n\}^*$?

Comment: No, it is a set with binary elements.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Over which alphabet $L$ is considered? In other words, of which free semigroup is $L$ a subset?

Comment: Sorry, it is on $A^*\times A^*$.

Comment: OK, but Kleene theorem is valid only for finite alphabets.

Comment: Yes, A is finite. Is L a regular language over $A\times A$ ?

Comment: @ Rudong: But then $(a^m,a^n)$ is not element of $A\times A$!

Comment: @Boris Novikov：Well ,I know $(a^m,a^n)$ is an element of $A^*\times A^*$ .My question: Given m,n$∈Z$,whether this language L over the alphabet $A\times A$ is regular or not ? And I think: if $m=n$, L is regular .Because in this case we can make a finite binary automaton to recognize L . But I don't know the case $m≠n$ .

Comment: @ Rudong: $L$ is not a language over $A\times A$ since $a^m\not \in A$.

Comment: @Boris Novikov:Sorry! Well , OK . I change my question:Given $m,n∈Z$,whether this language L on $A^*\times A^*$ is regular or not ? And I think: if $m=n$, L is regular .Because in this case we can make a finite binary automaton to recognize L . But I don't know the case $m≠n$ .

Comment: @Rudong: I think it would be better if you formulate a new and more exact question. A propos, what are of interest for you - regular languages or recognized ones?

Comment: @Boris Novikov: OK! Firstly, my question: Given $m,n∈Z$, whether this language $L$ on $A^*×A^*$ is regular or not? Then, we know there are two ways to proof whether a language is regular or not. One way: For a unitary set $L$, if we can show $L$ as finite regular languages with the operations: union, intersection, complement, concatenation and Kleene star, $L$ is regular; The other way: If we can make a finite automaton to recognize $L$ ($L$ maybe a $n$-tuples set), $L$ is regular. [cont]

Comment: At last, for above language $L$, I have proved $L$ is regular (making a finite binary automaton to recognize $L$) when $m=n$. And my interest: When $m≠n$, is $L$ also regular? Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: @Rudong:  Your question still doesn't make sense.  $L$ cannot be a regular language if you consider it as a 'language' over $A^*\times A^*$, because, as Boris has already pointed out, $A^*\times A^*$ is not a finite set.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure to interpret your question correctly, so I shall give two different possible scenarios. Let $A = \{a\}$.

(1) Let $n, m \in \mathbf{N}$. Then $a^n$ and $a^m$ are words of $A^*$ and $(a^n, a^m)$ is an element of $A^* \times A^*$. Further $L = (a^n, a^m)^*$ is a subset of $A^* \times A^*$.

(2) Let $n, m \in \mathbf{Z}$. Then $a^n$ and $a^m$ are words of the free group $FG(A)$ and $(a^n, a^m)$ is an element of $FG(A) \times FG(A)$. Further $L = (a^n, a^m)^*$ is a subset of $FG(A) \times FG(A)$.

Now, the term *regular* leads to a frequent confusion in both settings and should be avoided, or at least used with great care. There are indeed two distinct notions, the *rational* and the *recognizable* subsets of a monoid $M$, which coincide in $A^*$ (thanks to Kleene theorem) but fail to coincide in $A^* \times A^*$ and $FG(A) \times FG(A)$.

For instance your language $L$ is always a rational subset, but $(a, a)^*$ is not recognizable. Further, the rational subsets of $A^* \times A^*$ are **not** closed under complement.

Just to be complete, let me remind these two definitions: the *rational* subsets of $M$ form the smallest class of subsets of $M$ containing the singletons and closed under finite union, product and star. By construction, rational sets are closed under finite union, product and star.

A subset $K$ of $M$ is *recognizable* if there is a finite monoid $F$ and  a monoid morphism $f: M \to F$ such that $f^{-1}(f(K)) = K$. Recognizable sets are closed under finite union, finite intersection and complement, but are neither closed under product nor under star.

If $M$ is finitely generated, then every recognizable subset is rational, but there might be nonrecognizable sets that are rational, like in your example.

Answer (score 0):

As Boris has pointed out in the comments, so far your question doesn't make complete sense, because you haven't specified a *finite* alphabet $\Sigma$ such that $L\subseteq \Sigma^*$.

What I think you probably want is to consider $L$ as a language over $\Sigma = (A\cap\{\epsilon\})\times(A\cap\{\epsilon\})$, where we are simplifying strings over $\Sigma$ and writing them as pairs of strings over $A$, for example $(a,a)(a,\epsilon) = (a^2,a)$.

If this is what you mean, then for a given $m,n\in \mathbb{N}$, $L = \{(a^m,a^n)\}^*$ is indeed a regular language over $\Sigma$, which is obvious, since $(a^m,a^n)$ is just (the shorthand form of) a particular word over $\Sigma$, and so $(a^m,a^n)^*$ is a regular expression.