# Is this language regular?

Tags: formal-languages, automata, regular-language

Given $m,n∈Z$, A is a finite  alphabet set ,and $L=\{(a^m,a^n)\}^*$ is subset of $A^*\times A^*$ . Is this language regular ? For example, is $L=\{(a^3,a^7)\}^*$ regular ?

Here L is not the set $\{a^m,a^n\}^*$. $L$ is not a unitary  set ,but a binary set, which is a language over $\{A∪\{\$\}\}\times \{A∪\{\$\}\}$\{$(\$,\$)$}. .For example,if m=2,n=1,then$L=\{(a^2,a)\}^*,and $  $(a^4,a^2)=(a^2,a)(a^2,a)$ ,so $(a^4,a^2)∈L$. Can you write down the finite automata which recognize $\{(a^1,a^n)\}^*$ ?

Comment: What is the underlying alphabet for $L$? $A \times A$? Then the answer is "yes": First of all, show that $(a^1, a^n)^*$ and $(a^m,a^1)^*$ are regular (e.g., by using automata), and then calculate the intersection of these two languages.

Comment: @Johannes Kloos:Sorry，L is not a unitary set ,but a binary set. For example,if m=2,n=1,then$(a^2,a)、(a^4,a^2)∈L,and $ $(a^4,a^2)=(a^2,a)(a^2,a)$ . Please write down the finite automata which recognize $\{(a^1,a^n)\}^*$ .

Comment: It’s clear from his comment that @Johannes correctly understood the nature of $L$. Can you construct a DFA that recognizes $\{a^n\}^*$? That’s very straightforward, and if you have that, modifying it to recognize $\{\langle a^1,a^n\rangle\}^*$ is trivial.

Comment: @Johannes Kloos:L is a language over $\{A∪\{\$\}\}\times \{A∪\{\$\}\}$\\{$(\$,\$)$\}.

Comment: Please read more carefully: I did not say that $L$ was the set $\{a^m,a^n\}^*$. I said that it was exactly what you are describing, and so did Johannes. (Actually, it’s an abuse of notation to say that $L=\{\langle a^2,a\rangle\}^*$ and that $\langle a^4,a^2\rangle=\langle a^2,a\rangle\langle a^2,a\rangle$, since neither is correct as the symbols are normally used, but I abused them in the same way in my comment.) Now see if you can answer my question.

Comment: @ Brian M. Scott:Sorry,here L is not the set $\{a^m,a^n\}^*$. $L$ is not a unitary  set ,but a binary set, which is a language over $\{A∪\{\$\}\}\times \{A∪\{\$\}\}$\{$(\$,\$)$\}. .For example,if m=2,n=1,then$L=\{(a^2,a)\}^*=\{(a^2,a),(a^4,a^2),(a^6,a^3),(a^8,a^4),...\}$,because $(a^4,a^2)=(a^2,a)(a^2,a)$ ,$(a^6,a^3)=(a^2,a)(a^2,a)(a^2,a)$ ,$(a^8,a^4)=(a^2,a)(a^2,a)(a^2,a)(a^2,a)$ ,...

Comment: **Please read my last comment more carefully and stop telling me things that I already know.**

Comment: @ Brian M. Scott:Ok,I see .But I don't konw what DFA  is ?

Comment: I know $\{a^n\}^*$ is regular,but I don't know how to modify the automatic which recognize this language to be a DFA to recognize L.

Comment: Unitary to binary ? I don't think we can do it.

Comment: **And the definition of binary regular language is different from the definition of unitary regular language .**

Comment: @Andy: What makes a binary regular language different from a unitary regular language over a more complex alphabet? Unless you are using some definition I have never seen before (in which case, please cite the source where it is defined), $L$ will just be a regular language over the alphabet $(A \cup \{ \$ \})^2$. Anyway, the automaton is straightforward to construct: Take the automaton for $(a^n)^*$ and modify the transition labels from $a$ to $(a,a)$.

Comment: If you transite labels from a to (a,a),the automaton will  recognize the language $L'=\{(a^m,a^m)\}^*$,not the  above language .

Comment: @Johannes Kloos,@ Brian M. Scott:The difference between binary regular language and unitary regular language :Let $L=\{(w,w')|w∈L^1,w'∈L^2,and L^1,L^2$ are  unitary  languages \} be a binary language,the length of w and w' maybe not all the same (suppose some |w|>|w'|).Firstly , we must add \$ 's behind w' such that all |w|=|w'$...|,then we get a new language L'. And we will say L is regular if and only if L' is regular.

Comment: I don't understand how $(a^2,a)$ or $(a^m,a^n)$ is a word over the alphabet $(A \cup \{\$\})^2$, and how $(a^4,a^2) = (a^2,a)(a^2,a)$

Comment: * is Kleene star symbol.

Comment: @Andy: Ok, this is a slightly different problem. Nevertheless, it can be solved with a similar approach, which follows from my proposed solution plus your definition. I'll sketch it in more detail tonight, if needed.

Comment: @ Johannes Kloos:Ok,I wait for you, thank you!

Comment: @ Johannes Kloos:Sorry,I don't think the language you made is the same as mine. Firstly, you don't need to add \$ into $A'$ ,$S_{1}=\{(a^{mk_{1}},g_{1})|k_{1}∈N,g_{1}∈A^*\}$and $S_{2}=\{(g_{2},a^{nk_{2}})|k_{2}∈N,g_{2}∈A^*\}$ are regular, so is $S_{1}∩S_{2}=\{(a^{mk_{1}},a^{nk_{2}})|k_{1},k_{2}∈N\}$.But the above language $L≠S_{1}∩S_{2}$,since $L=\{(a^m,a^n)\}^*=\{(a^{mk},a^{nk})|k∈N\}$.Actually,$L⊂S_{1}∩S_{2}$.

For example,the element $(a^{2m},a^n)$ is in $S_{1}∩S_{2}$ ,but not in L.

Comment: This question seems to be strongly related to this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/420985/whether-l-am-an-is-regular-or-not

Answer (score 1):

The languages described in this question are indeed not regular in general.

Consider the simplest example, $(a,aa)^*$. According to the description of binary languages, this is equivalent to the language $L = \{ (u,v) \mid u = a^n\$^n, v = a^{2n} \}$. But if this language were regular, so would be its projection to the first component, by closure of regular languages under homomorphisms. Thus, $a^n\$^n$ would be regular, contradiction to a well-
known result.

Comment: :The set $\{a^n\$^n|n∈Z\}$ is not a language over A, since the simbol $\$∉A$. And if we want to  define a homomorphism , we first define a map $f$ from $A\times A $ to $A$ (or $A^*$),then the map extends a homomorphism $f^*$from $A^*\times A^*$ to $A^*$. And then if L is a regular language over $\{A∪\{\$\}\}\times \{A∪\{\$\}\}\｝\{(\$,\$)\}$（  L is regular language over A）,so is $f^*(L)$  ($f^{*-1}(L) )$.

Comment: I never said that $\{a^n\$^n\}$ is regular over $A$ - it is a language over $A \cup \{ \$ \}$. Obviously, the projection to the first component induces a homomorphism of regular languages, so I don't see what exact problem you are talking about.

Comment: Sorry,I don't agree with you. I am confused with the  homomorphism you definied.

Comment: Take the map $\pi_1: (A \cup \{ \$ \})^2 \setminus \{ (\$,\$)\} \to A \cup \{ \$ \}, (a, b) \mapsto a$. This clearly extends to a homomorphism $f: ((A \cup \{ \$ \})^2 \setminus \{ (\$, \$) \})^* \to (A \cup \{ \$ \})^*$ where $f(u,v) = u$.

Comment: But we don't  define homomorphism like this,we first remove $.

Comment: You may not do it, but I do. This is, essentially, the point of the exercise - I explicitly *want* to keep the $\$$ around here!

Comment: Maybe you are right.But it seems not so much convictive.